# Old tables data becomes NULL after adding a new column with a SELECT in IMPLA/HIVE

Tags: sql, hive, inner-join, hiveql, impala

I'm trying to add data to new column in Impala with a (SELECT,JOIN) query, once I add the data to the new column, I lose all the other column's data (they become NULL).

Here I create the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE mng_exp.KPI_LATENCE_JOUR
(
    CODEINSEE       INT,
    IMEI            BIGINT,
    SEMAINE         INT,
    MOYENNE_LATENCE INT,
    MAXIMUM_LATENCE INT,
    MINIMUM_LATENCE INT
)
```

I add data into the table:

```
INSERT INTO mng_exp.KPI_LATENCE_JOUR (CODEINSEE,IMEI, SEMAINE, MOYENNE_LATENCE,MAXIMUM_LATENCE,MINIMUM_LATENCE,TRANCHE_DE_LATENCE) 
SELECT codeinsee, device_dim__imei as IMEI,weekofyear(jour) as SEMAINE, cast(round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) as integer) as MOYENNE_LATENCE, 
cast(round(avg(rtt_max_ms)) as integer) as MAXIMUM_LATENCE, cast(round(avg(rtt_min_ms)) as integer) as MINIMUM_LATENCE , 
CASE WHEN ( round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) > 0 and round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) <= 10 ) THEN 0 
WHEN ( round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) > 10 and round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) <= 20 ) THEN 1 
WHEN ( round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) > 20 and round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) <= 30 ) THEN 2 
WHEN ( round(avg(rtt_avg_ms)) > 30 ) THEN 3 END AS Tranche_de_latence

FROM mscore.mscore where operateur = 'BT_HZ' and year(jour) = 2019 group by device_dim__imei,weekofyear(jour),codeinsee 



# I  Add a new column

ALTER TABLE mng_exp.kpi_latence_jour ADD COLUMNS (srv_id BIGINT)

#Here data is good and new column srv_id is NULL
```

I add data to new column:

```
INSERT INTO mng_exp.KPI_LATENCE_jour (srv_id) 
    SELECT CAST(dng_fai_cli_eqt_iad.srv_id AS BIGINT)
    FROM msf_exploratoire.dng_fai_cli_eqt_iad
    INNER JOIN mng_exp.kpi_latence_jour ON (dng_fai_cli_eqt_iad.num_serie = kpi_latence_jour.imei);
```

Here is the problem: `srv_id` is OK, and the old columns become NULL.

I have no query error but I lose all the old data

Comment: You inserting only one column. Add all other columns also

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, itryed that but i get an error in the select line, do you have an idea how i can write it  ? thank you in advance

Comment: Added my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You inserting only one column. Use INSERT OVERWRITE and add all other columns:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE mng_exp.KPI_LATENCE_jour (CODEINSEE,IMEI, SEMAINE, MOYENNE_LATENCE,MAXIMUM_LATENCE,MINIMUM_LATENCE,TRANCHE_DE_LATENCE,srv_id) 
    SELECT b.CODEINSEE,
           b.IMEI,
           b.SEMAINE,
           b.MOYENNE_LATENCE,
           b.MAXIMUM_LATENCE,
           b.MINIMUM_LATENCE,
           b.TRANCHE_DE_LATENCE,
           CAST(a.srv_id AS BIGINT) srv_id
      FROM msf_exploratoire.dng_fai_cli_eqt_iad a
           INNER JOIN mng_exp.kpi_latence_jour  b ON (a.num_serie = b.imei)
      ;
```

Comment: Excellent ! works perfectly thank you sir/mam ! Have a nice day !

Comment: Hello @leftjoin, i tryed the same code to add other columns but the shell stops at 100%, do you have an idea why it can not add theses columns ?

Comment: @FirasMegrahi you can do the same without column list after table name (CODEINSEE,IMEI, ...). Just keep columns in the select in the same order and number as they are in the table DDL

Comment: @FirasMegrahi No, I do not understand what do you mean the shell stops at 100% Do you mean map-reduce stops? Check you do not have skew in num_serie

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you lost all the old data or if you execute:

`select * from mng_exp.KPI_LATENCE_JOUR`

You will see also:

1. the first set of rows (the ones where srv_id is null);
2. the second set of rows - the ones where the only populated column is srv_id?

What you want is to update the SRV_ID for the first set of rows.

You can see more details about update in imapala, [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/impala_kudu.html).

Comment: perfect! I was about to write this down! :)

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer, i verified again now and yes i lost all the old data, so there is not two sets of data. :(

Comment: are you sure that the insert statement was "Insert into mng_exp.KPI_LATENCE_jour (srv_id) " or it was "INSERT **OVERWRITE** TABLE mng_exp.KPI_LATENCE_jour (srv_id) "?

Comment: it was an INSERT INTO, i tryed an insert overwrite but i had the same problem.